# How to upload newly created jsPdf file to server instead of saving it in local computer?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, jspdf, form-data

I am using html2canvas to create picture and jsPdf to create a pdf file. I want to upload this newly created file to the server instead of saving it to the local directory. Every time when I upload the file, it only uploads its name, not file.

On line no. 7 of the code, I also tried `formData.append("file", photo+'.jpg');` but nothing happens.

```
    html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
      var pageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
      var pdf = new jsPDF('', 'pt', 'a4');\
      let photo = pdf.addImage(pageData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 595.28, 592.28/canvas.width * canvas.height );

      let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      let formData = new FormData();

      formData.append("file", photo);                                
      req.open("POST", '/image/file');
      req.send(formData);

    });
```

No error shows, it uploads but the name of the file NOT the file.